# How to move uiview on circle trajectory?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, core-animation

Is there any way to animate uiview moving with cicle trajectory?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to create a circular path and animate your view on the path. You can use UIBezierPath to create a circular path . [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4708894/641062) is an example that does what exactly you want.

Comment: Can't understand how to use bezierpath for moving imageview

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of options. Probably the simplest is to place your view on a parent view, and then animate rotating the parent view around its Z axis.

I guess you could also build a transform that shifts your view, then rotates it, and animate the transform to different rotation values. I'd have to tinker with that. I know the first approach would be quick and easy to set up.

As the other poster said, you could also create a keyframe animation that uses a CGPath to animate your view along a curve that approximated the shape of a circle, but that would be much more work.

Comment: This is a very interesting answer! I can't believe I didn't think of before! It's by far the simplest answer if all you have to do is to rotate in a circular path!