# Animating GMSMarker in a circular path

Tags: core-animation, google-maps-sdk-ios

I understand how to normally animation other CALayers in a circular path based on this SO question:
[iPhone - How to make a circle path for a CAKeyframeAnimation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804453/iphone-how-to-make-a-circle-path-for-a-cakeyframeanimation/4708894#4708894)

However, the GMSMarkerLayer is a special subclass of CALayers that does not seem to respond to the "position" keypath (following instructions in that link does nothing that I can visibly see) but instead will respond to the "latitude" and "longitude" keypaths instead.

Here's the code that I've tried:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *circlePathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
CGMutablePathRef circularPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGRect pathRect = CGRectMake(marker.position.latitude, marker.position.longitude, 0.001, 0.001);
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(circularPath, NULL, pathRect);
circlePathAnimation.path = circularPath;
circlePathAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
circlePathAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

[marker.layer addAnimation:circlePathAnimation forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"circular-%@", marker.description]];
CGPathRelease(circularPath);
```

Since the keyframe animation will use the "position" keypath, how can I convert that into 2 separate keypaths (latitude and longitude) so I can animate the marker in a circle on the map?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question, are you interested in animating a circle on the earth, or a circle on the screen? If you are interested in animating something like a geodesic on the earth, then interpolating a series of short line segments manually is your path forward. If you are interested in animating a circle on the screen, then raising a feature request for animating `offset`s on https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Feature%20Request

Comment: Hi @Brett Thanks for your question. I want to animate the marker in a circular path on the earth's surface. It's interesting that the GMSMarkerLayer does NOT allow me to make use of the "position" keypath and directly translate it into "latitude" and "longitude" since that would immediately solve my problem. Interpolating a series of short line segments would work but would require me to animate the lat and lon separately using their individual keypath, do you happen to know if there are more efficient ways to go about that?

Comment: Please feel free to raise a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Feature%20Request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As currently I cannot use the "position" keypath for animating, I ended up animating it using the "latitude" and "longitude" keypaths separately.

First calculate the points and add them to 2 separate arrays, one for latitude value (y) and one for longitude (x) and then use the values property in CAKeyFrameAnimation to animate. Create 2 CAKeyFrameAnimation objects (1 for each axis) and group them together using CAAnimationGroup and animate them together to form a circle.

In my equation I vary the length of the radius on each axis so that I can also generate an oval path.

```
    NSMutableArray *latitudes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:21];
    NSMutableArray *longitudes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:21];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        CGFloat radians = (float)i * ((2.0f * M_PI) / 20.0f);

        // Calculate the x,y coordinate using the angle
        CGFloat x = hDist * cosf(radians);
        CGFloat y = vDist * sinf(radians);

        // Calculate the real lat and lon using the
        // current lat and lon as center points.
        y = marker.position.latitude + y;
        x = marker.position.longitude + x;


        [longitudes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:x]];
        [latitudes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:y]];
    }

    CAKeyframeAnimation *horizontalAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"longitude"];
    horizontalAnimation.values = longitudes;
    horizontalAnimation.duration = duration;

    CAKeyframeAnimation *verticleAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"latitude"];
    verticleAnimation.values = latitudes;
    verticleAnimation.duration = duration;

    CAAnimationGroup *group = [[CAAnimationGroup alloc] init];
    group.animations = @[horizontalAnimation, verticleAnimation];
    group.duration = duration;
    group.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [marker.layer addAnimation:group forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"circular-%@",marker.description]];
```