# How to animate GMSURLTileLayer

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, core-animation

I have an array of last 10 *epochs* time.
 And I want to create an animation GMSURLTileLayer with these *epochs*.

> I tried to integrate with for loop but it is not working.

This is my code:

```
let epochs = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

private func configureRadarForGoogle(epoch: Int) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
        let url: GMSTileURLConstructor = {(x, y, zoom) in
            let urltemplate = "https://tilecache.rainviewer.com/v2/radar/\(epoch)/512/\(zoom)/\(x)/\(y)/2/1_1.png"
            return URL(string: urltemplate)
        }
        let layer = GMSURLTileLayer(urlConstructor: url)
        layer.zIndex = 5
        layer.map = self.mapView
    }
}

private func startAnimation() {
    for epoch in self.epochs {
        sleep(1)
        configureRadarForGoogle(epoch: epoch)
    }
}
```

Is anyone know a better solution? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `GMSMarkerLayer`, which is a subclass of `GMSOverlayLayer`, available on a per-marker basis, that allows animation of several properties of its associated `GMSMarker`

Now to Animate you can calculate the points and add them to 2 separate arrays, one for latitude value (y) and one for longitude (x) and then use the values property in CAKeyFrameAnimation to animate as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227017/animating-gmsmarker-in-a-circular-path)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I cannot find how to cast GMSURLTileLayer to GMSMarkerLayer. I need to get tiles from the server with {x} {y} and {z}. Can I still cast it?